# Goldbach’s conjecture (java)

Tags: java, arrays, primes, goldbach-conjecture

I need to print out Goldbach’s conjecture for the first 1000 elements (in the code you'll notice I am only working with 100 elements for simplicity and that I am including 1 as a prime). I understand that Goldbach’s conjecture says that every even number can be expressed as a sum of two primes. My program works, but it's skipping certain even numbers such as 8, 12, etc, and I'm unsure how to fix this. Please help me figure this out.

```
public class GoldbachClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int i;
    int num = 0;
    int maxCheck = 100; // limit set to which you want to find prime numbers
    boolean isPrime = true;

    int[] primeNumbers = new int [maxCheck];

    //Start loop 1 to maxCheck
    for (i = 1; i <= maxCheck; i++) 
    {
        isPrime = CheckPrime(i);
        if (isPrime) 
        {
            primeNumbers[i] = i;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to " + maxCheck + " are:");
    // Print prime numbers from 1 to maxCheck
    for (int j = 1; j < primeNumbers.length; j++)
    {
        if (primeNumbers[j] != 0){
        System.out.printf("%d ", primeNumbers[j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int j = 1; j < primeNumbers.length; j++)
    {
        if (primeNumbers[j] != 0)
        {
            num = primeNumbers[j] + primeNumbers[j];
        System.out.printf("%d = %d + %d\n", num, primeNumbers[j], primeNumbers[j]);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean CheckPrime(int numberToCheck) {
    int remainder;
    for (int i = 2; i <= numberToCheck / 2; i++) {
        remainder = numberToCheck % i;
        //if remainder is 0 than numberToCheckber is not prime and break loop. Elese continue loop
        if (remainder == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}  
}
```

Comment: `I am including 1 as a prime` rightfully so, 1 isn't prime. Also your primeNumbers array is only populated in slots which are themselves prime, so you'll have a lot of 0's in there (which you do correctly check later on). If you use a List you can just throw your numbers in there without worrying about that. Also when generating the list of primes you can `i=i+2` instead of `i++` as there are no even primes except for `2` itself. Ultimately you're also checking the wrong condition: Goldbach says that every number is the sum of two primes; not twice a prime.

Comment: I figured you'd probably learn more if I just made you a fix rather than talking you through it point-by-point, so here you go: https://pastebin.com/rqWGesCu

Comment: Thanks. I haven't been taught about lists in java, so I would prefer using an array, but I'll check out your code using the list. I wrote my code as such because it assures that a prime is added to a prime, how should I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's address some specific problems with your code: Goldbach's conjecture only applies to *even* numbers, but your code outputs *odd* numbers too, so we'll filter for even results; your prime test checks up to `numberToCheck/2` instead of the square root of `numberToCheck`; your final production loop really needs to be a pair of nested loops:

```
public class GoldbachClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int maxCheck = 100;

        int[] primeNumbers = new int[maxCheck];

        for (int number = 1, index = 0; number <= maxCheck; number++, index++) {
            if (isPrime(number)) {
                primeNumbers[index] = number;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to " + maxCheck + " are:");
        for (int index = 0; index < primeNumbers.length; index++) {
            if (primeNumbers[index] != 0) {
                System.out.printf("%d ", primeNumbers[index]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < primeNumbers.length; i++) {
            if (primeNumbers[i] == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            for (int j = i; j < primeNumbers.length; j++) {
                if (primeNumbers[j] == 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                int number = primeNumbers[i] + primeNumbers[j];

                if (number % 2 == 0) { // conjecture only applies to even numbers
                    System.out.printf("%d = %d + %d\n", number, primeNumbers[i], primeNumbers[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int number) {

        if (number < 2 || number % 2 == 0) {
            return (number == 2);
        }

        for (int odd = 3; odd * odd <= number; odd += 2) {
            if (number % odd == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Output filtered through Unix sort:

```
% java GoldbachClass | sort -n
Prime numbers from 1 to 100 are:
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 
4 = 2 + 2
6 = 3 + 3
8 = 3 + 5
10 = 3 + 7
10 = 5 + 5
12 = 5 + 7
14 = 3 + 11
14 = 7 + 7
16 = 3 + 13
16 = 5 + 11
18 = 5 + 13
18 = 7 + 11
20 = 3 + 17
20 = 7 + 13
22 = 11 + 11
22 = 3 + 19
22 = 5 + 17
24 = 11 + 13
24 = 5 + 19
24 = 7 + 17
26 = 13 + 13
26 = 3 + 23
26 = 7 + 19
28 = 11 + 17
28 = 5 + 23
30 = 11 + 19
30 = 13 + 17
30 = 7 + 23
32 = 13 + 19
32 = 3 + 29
34 = 11 + 23
34 = 17 + 17
34 = 3 + 31
34 = 5 + 29
36 = 13 + 23
36 = 17 + 19
36 = 5 + 31
36 = 7 + 29
38 = 19 + 19
38 = 7 + 31
40 = 11 + 29
40 = 17 + 23
40 = 3 + 37
42 = 11 + 31
42 = 13 + 29
42 = 19 + 23
42 = 5 + 37
44 = 13 + 31
44 = 3 + 41
44 = 7 + 37
46 = 17 + 29
46 = 23 + 23
46 = 3 + 43
46 = 5 + 41
48 = 11 + 37
48 = 17 + 31
48 = 19 + 29
48 = 5 + 43
48 = 7 + 41
50 = 13 + 37
50 = 19 + 31
50 = 3 + 47
50 = 7 + 43
52 = 11 + 41
52 = 23 + 29
52 = 5 + 47
54 = 11 + 43
54 = 13 + 41
54 = 17 + 37
54 = 23 + 31
54 = 7 + 47
56 = 13 + 43
56 = 19 + 37
56 = 3 + 53
58 = 11 + 47
58 = 17 + 41
58 = 29 + 29
58 = 5 + 53
60 = 13 + 47
60 = 17 + 43
60 = 19 + 41
60 = 23 + 37
60 = 29 + 31
60 = 7 + 53
62 = 19 + 43
62 = 3 + 59
62 = 31 + 31
64 = 11 + 53
64 = 17 + 47
64 = 23 + 41
64 = 3 + 61
64 = 5 + 59
66 = 13 + 53
66 = 19 + 47
66 = 23 + 43
66 = 29 + 37
66 = 5 + 61
66 = 7 + 59
68 = 31 + 37
68 = 7 + 61
70 = 11 + 59
70 = 17 + 53
70 = 23 + 47
70 = 29 + 41
70 = 3 + 67
72 = 11 + 61
72 = 13 + 59
72 = 19 + 53
72 = 29 + 43
72 = 31 + 41
72 = 5 + 67
74 = 13 + 61
74 = 3 + 71
74 = 31 + 43
74 = 37 + 37
74 = 7 + 67
76 = 17 + 59
76 = 23 + 53
76 = 29 + 47
76 = 3 + 73
76 = 5 + 71
78 = 11 + 67
78 = 17 + 61
78 = 19 + 59
78 = 31 + 47
78 = 37 + 41
78 = 5 + 73
78 = 7 + 71
80 = 13 + 67
80 = 19 + 61
80 = 37 + 43
80 = 7 + 73
82 = 11 + 71
82 = 23 + 59
82 = 29 + 53
82 = 3 + 79
82 = 41 + 41
84 = 11 + 73
84 = 13 + 71
84 = 17 + 67
84 = 23 + 61
84 = 31 + 53
84 = 37 + 47
84 = 41 + 43
84 = 5 + 79
86 = 13 + 73
86 = 19 + 67
86 = 3 + 83
86 = 43 + 43
86 = 7 + 79
88 = 17 + 71
88 = 29 + 59
88 = 41 + 47
88 = 5 + 83
90 = 11 + 79
90 = 17 + 73
90 = 19 + 71
90 = 23 + 67
90 = 29 + 61
90 = 31 + 59
90 = 37 + 53
90 = 43 + 47
90 = 7 + 83
92 = 13 + 79
92 = 19 + 73
92 = 3 + 89
92 = 31 + 61
94 = 11 + 83
94 = 23 + 71
94 = 41 + 53
94 = 47 + 47
94 = 5 + 89
96 = 13 + 83
96 = 17 + 79
96 = 23 + 73
96 = 29 + 67
96 = 37 + 59
96 = 43 + 53
96 = 7 + 89
98 = 19 + 79
98 = 31 + 67
98 = 37 + 61
100 = 11 + 89
100 = 17 + 83
100 = 29 + 71
100 = 3 + 97
100 = 41 + 59
100 = 47 + 53
102 = 13 + 89
102 = 19 + 83
102 = 23 + 79
102 = 29 + 73
102 = 31 + 71
102 = 41 + 61
102 = 43 + 59
102 = 5 + 97
104 = 31 + 73
104 = 37 + 67
104 = 43 + 61
104 = 7 + 97
106 = 17 + 89
106 = 23 + 83
106 = 47 + 59
106 = 53 + 53
108 = 11 + 97
108 = 19 + 89
108 = 29 + 79
108 = 37 + 71
108 = 41 + 67
108 = 47 + 61
110 = 13 + 97
110 = 31 + 79
110 = 37 + 73
110 = 43 + 67
112 = 23 + 89
112 = 29 + 83
112 = 41 + 71
112 = 53 + 59
114 = 17 + 97
114 = 31 + 83
114 = 41 + 73
114 = 43 + 71
114 = 47 + 67
114 = 53 + 61
116 = 19 + 97
116 = 37 + 79
116 = 43 + 73
118 = 29 + 89
118 = 47 + 71
118 = 59 + 59
120 = 23 + 97
120 = 31 + 89
120 = 37 + 83
120 = 41 + 79
120 = 47 + 73
120 = 53 + 67
120 = 59 + 61
122 = 43 + 79
122 = 61 + 61
124 = 41 + 83
124 = 53 + 71
126 = 29 + 97
126 = 37 + 89
126 = 43 + 83
126 = 47 + 79
126 = 53 + 73
126 = 59 + 67
128 = 31 + 97
128 = 61 + 67
130 = 41 + 89
130 = 47 + 83
130 = 59 + 71
132 = 43 + 89
132 = 53 + 79
132 = 59 + 73
132 = 61 + 71
134 = 37 + 97
134 = 61 + 73
134 = 67 + 67
136 = 47 + 89
136 = 53 + 83
138 = 41 + 97
138 = 59 + 79
138 = 67 + 71
140 = 43 + 97
140 = 61 + 79
140 = 67 + 73
142 = 53 + 89
142 = 59 + 83
142 = 71 + 71
144 = 47 + 97
144 = 61 + 83
144 = 71 + 73
146 = 67 + 79
146 = 73 + 73
148 = 59 + 89
150 = 53 + 97
150 = 61 + 89
150 = 67 + 83
150 = 71 + 79
152 = 73 + 79
154 = 71 + 83
156 = 59 + 97
156 = 67 + 89
156 = 73 + 83
158 = 61 + 97
158 = 79 + 79
160 = 71 + 89
162 = 73 + 89
162 = 79 + 83
164 = 67 + 97
166 = 83 + 83
168 = 71 + 97
168 = 79 + 89
170 = 73 + 97
172 = 83 + 89
176 = 79 + 97
178 = 89 + 89
180 = 83 + 97
186 = 89 + 97
194 = 97 + 97
%
```

The results get ragged at the end due to our arbitrary prime cutoff `maxCheck`.